# Array to ignore of element is misisng

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of rows to be added into array. If one of the element is missing then would need to ignore the record. Can someone please suggest how to do this in JS?

here is the data to be added into new array:

```
{"start":"20161229T160000","end":"20161229T164500","summary":"JJ1"},
{"start":"20170106T180000","end":"20170106T183000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR","summary":"JJ2"},
```

I tried checking `if (rrule !==null)` or `(rrule!='undefined')`... nothing worked.. its keeps adding the row into array list..:(

I don't want to add first record  into array..as `rrule`  element is missing.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Do you want to test explicitly for `start`, `end`, `rule`, and `summary`, or would it be enough to test that each object has at least four properties?

Comment: I am passing the data from different array(which was extracted from raw ics data)

Comment: The second element has a `rule` property. What's `rrule`?

Answer (score 1):

If `item` is one of the data objects, you can use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)  to test:

```
if (item.hasOwnProperty('rule')) {
    // add to array
}
```

That will work even if the value of `rule` is a "falsy" value (e.g., `{...,"rule": 0,...}`). If you want to exclude those as well, just use

```
if (item.rule) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is an array of objects, you can easily get an array of just the ones with the required properties by using the [array `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var input = [
     {"start":"20161229T160000","end":"20161229T164500","summary":"JJ1"},
     {"start":"20170106T180000","end":"20170106T183000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR","summary":"JJ2"},
     {"start":"20161229T160000"},
     {"start":"20170205T180000","end":"20170206T183000","rule":"FREQ=WHATEVER;BYDAY=FR","summary":"XYZ"}
];

var output = input.filter(function(item) {
    return item.start != undefined
        && item.end != undefined
        && item.rule != undefined
        && item.summary != undefined;
});

console.log(output);
```

Your attempt `if (rrule !==null)` didn't work because a missing property is not `null`. Your attempt `(rrule!='undefined')` didn't work because it was testing for the *string* `'undefined'`, not the value `undefined`. Note that if it would be valid for a property to exist with the value `undefined` then you should test with `item.hasOwnProperty('rule')` rather than `item.rule != undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and that make sense and got it why it didn't worked before....